Disable `org.glassfish` logging when running `mvn clean package`
I'm a new Java developer having issues with logging output when running mvn clean package. I'm getting lots of chatter in the terminal output from what appears to be one dependency, org.glassfish. I'm including some sample output, including a count of the number of times it occurs in a single run.
 177 INFO: Creating InMemoryTestContainer configured at the base URI http://localhost:9998/
 177 Apr 02, 2024 10:08 AM org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory$InMemoryTestContainer <init>
  46 INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
  46 INFO: Stopped listener bound to [localhost:9998]
  46 INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:9998]
  38 Apr 02, 2024 10:08 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
  38 Apr 02, 2024 10:08 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
  38 Apr 02, 2024 10:08 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
  31 INFO: Creating GrizzlyTestContainer configured at the base URI http://localhost:9998/
  30 Apr 02, 2024 10:08 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext deploy
  23 Apr 02, 2024 10:08 AM org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer <init>
  23 Apr 02, 2024 10:08 AM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
  15 INFO: [TestContext] Servlet [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer] registered for url pattern(s) [[/*]].
  15 INFO: Starting application [TestContext] ...
  15 INFO: Creating GrizzlyWebTestContainer configured at the base URI http://localhost:9998/
  15 INFO: Application [TestContext] is ready to service requests.  Root: [].
  15 Apr 02, 2024 10:08 AM org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyWebTestContainer <init>
  15 Apr 02, 2024 10:08 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext initServlets

We have some logging config stored in a logging.properties file defined in pom.xml using the maven-surefire-plugin.
I've tried setting logging levels for org.glassfish.grizzly and org.glassfish.jersey but I don't know if I did it correctly, as it didn't seem to help.
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
      <propertyName>java.util.logging.config.file</propertyName>
      <buildDirectory>src/test/resources/logging.properties</buildDirectory>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
    <argLine>-Dcom.redhat.fips=false</argLine>
    <includes>
      <include>TestSuite.java</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

A quick update. I came across a blog post which suggested that the -q flag might help. Running mvn clean package -q removes all of the test progress statements, but leaves all of the statements I'm trying to get rid of.
Update #2. I did a bisect to find out when the last time the logging wasn't there and found that it changed after we made this update to our pom.xml.
This is the current node:
<systemPropertyVariables>
  <propertyName>java.util.logging.config.file</propertyName>
<buildDirectory>src/test/resources/logging.properties</buildDirectory>
</systemPropertyVariables>

I changed it back to this and no more extraneous logging. But a specific unit test now fails. 
<systemProperties>
  <property>
  <name>java.util.logging.config.file</name>
  <value>src/test/resources/logging.properties</value>
  </property>
</systemProperties>

